# Regex match from right to left

Tags: php, regex

I wanted to match something from right to left, below is one of such example.

```
100abababab3x3x3xx1000morewords
```

If i want to match something between  and last `xx` and immediate previous `ab` and get `3x3x3`

I tried something like below , but it matches `ababab3x3x3`

```
preg_match('/ab(.*?)xx/',$text,$totmat);
```

Note : please don't recommend strrev.

Above example is just for illustration , all i wanted to do is match from right to left.

Comment: Cthulhu is coming! Joke apart, it is not actually *text* but a possibly nested `HTML` structure - use a parser and appropriate `xpath` queries instead.

Comment: there are like 20 different tables and that page does not follow any w3 standards , so please answer it in general regex way. how to match 333 from ababab333xx1000morewords perspective

Comment: Nope. See, the point is, `xpath` queries *in combination*  with a regular expression are really powerful and you should really use them. Regular expressions alone lead to a dead end here, really.

Comment: Yes i understand , please see my edit.

Comment: Regex is not the best for what you are trying to achieve - look into php's DOMDocument - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/RmOOPh/1/

Comment: @Mohammad : wat about </td> <td align="right"> 100 </td>

Comment: In your regex you need to restrict it to a particular character set instead of dot else it will match anything and may give you undesired results. Try with this regex <td align="right">([\d,. ]*)<\/td> <td colspan="4"> But with this way you need to know in advance what all characters may appear in your intended text.

Comment: @Graciewilliams If your html be `</td> <td align="right"> 100 </td>` how you want to get **7,433.00** from it?

Comment: It looks like one is money and the other is a quantity, can you rely on that information? `/\d*?,?\d*?\.\d{2}/`. This looks for any amount of digits, followed by an optional ',', then any amount of digits, a dot and 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the most optimized way or not? But this will work for you if you use the combination of **Look ahead positive** `(?=)` and **Look behind positive** `(?<=)`. See [regex](https://regex101.com/r/SMzu1r/1)

```
<?php

$re = '/\w+(?<=ab)(.*?)(?=xx)/m';
$str = '100abababab3x3x3xx1000morewords';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the full matched result
echo $matches[0][1];
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/db69N

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '100abababab3x3x3xx1000morewords';
preg_match('/ab((?:(?!ab).)*)xx/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ab3x3x3xx
    [1] => 3x3x3
)
```

**>Explanation:**

```
ab              : literally ab
  (             : start group 1
    (?:         : start non capture group
      (?!ab)    : negative lookahead, make sure we doon't have ab
      .         : any character but newline
    )*          : end group, may appear 0 or more times
  )             : end group 1
xx              : literally xx
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other approaches than a regex to this kind of problem that would be close to twice faster in computing time.

Here for example :

```
$str = "100abababab3x3x3xx1000morewords";
$result = explode("ab", explode("xx", $str)[0]);
var_dump(end($result));
```

First occurence of explode split the string in two between the "xx" characters. We're only interested by the left part (Index 0).

Second occurence of explode split the string with the caracters ab. We're only interested by the last occurence of ab. Therefore `var_dump(end($result));` prints the expected result.